# Sound delay after repair

Tags: guitar

I dropped my guitar a while ago, the fret board came off the neck so I removed the strings and glued it back on, along with putting on new strings. I never touched or removed any of the electronics but now I have a delay in the sound...any help?

Comment: A delay? I'm not sure how a mechanical problem caused by dropping it could lead to a delay. Can you upload a sound or video example?

Comment: I'm intrigued... sounds a bit quantum to me ;)

Comment: You didn't put the 'board on the neck on back to front, so the sound has further to go...?

Comment: Maybe it's not the guitar. Have you tried it with a different amp, without effects?